# Copy tables between databases on Cbuilder

Tags: mysql, odbc, dbx

I am trying to optimize my code to copy about 7000 records from one table to another.

```
SQLQuery1->Open();

while (!SQLQuery1->Eof)
    {
     Table1->Append();
       Table1->FieldByName("terc1_cod")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("terc1_cod")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("terc1_nome1")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("terc1_nome1")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("terc1_nome2")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("terc1_nome2")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("terc1_morada")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("terc1_morada")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("terc1_local")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("terc1_local")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("cdpst_cod")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("cdpst_cod")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("terc1_nctrb")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("terc1_nctrb")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("conc_descr1")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("conc_descr1")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("freg_descr1")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("freg_descr1")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("terc1_telef")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("terc1_telef")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("terc1_telefax")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("terc1_telefax")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("terc1_email")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("terc1_email")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("terc1_estado")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("terc1_estado")->Value;
       Table1->FieldByName("alfa01")->Value = SQLQuery1->FieldByName("alfa01")->Value;
     Table1->Post();
     SQLQuery1->Next();
     ProgressBar1->StepIt();
    }    
    SQLQuery1->Close();
```

SQLQuery1 is a DBX connection to a ODBC, and Table1 is Mysql DB. This takes about 3 minutes to copy 7000 rows. How can I speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a long time since I worked with those components, but the way I used to do it was something like this:

```
qryOracle->SQL->Clear();
qryOracle->SQL->Add( "select * from " + sSrcTable; );
qryOracle->Prepare();
qryOracle->Open();

tblDest->TableName = "whatever";
tblDest->BatchMove( frmData->sqlQ, batCopy );
```